# view data from joined table in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

im trying to view data from 2 seperate table, but this error came out:

```
"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\testsubject\User\inventory.php on line 18"
```

this is my PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT storage_details.itemCODE,storage_details.pckgeID,storage_details.cndition,storage_details.duration,pckge_info.price,storage_details.status 
    FROM storage_details
    INNER JOIN pckge_info
    ON storage_details.pckgeID=pckge_info.pckgeID";
$result = $link->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "itemcode: " . $row["itemCODE"]. " - packageid: " . $row["pckgeID"]. "condition: " . $row["cndition"]. "duration: " . $row["duration"]. " status: " . $row["price"]. " " . $row["status"]."<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: which one is line 18? I can only guess that it's either `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {` or `$result = $link->query($sql);`, anyway, show us please the big picture (prior code)

Comment: yes.. its if ($result->num_rows > 0)

Comment: i cant give u the full code because it wont let me post since my post has too much codes.the upper part is only require database connection and session

Comment: did you try to run this query directly on mysql?

Comment: i got this error "#1054 - Unknown column 'pckge_info.pckgeID' in 'on clause' "

Comment: @MorKadosh ah i see the error now.thanks Mor.its working now

Comment: this could explain why the results object does not populate right. are you sure the "pckageID" is the right column name on "pckgae_info"? usually, it will be just "id"

Comment: great. anyway, as suggested below, your could should be able to deffend itself. I mean, you might need some error handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is most likely returning a database error. num_rows is trying a evaluate a null object. Have your script die on error and return the message. That will point you in the right direction once you figure out where you've gone wrong.

```
if ($result === false) { die(mysql_error($link)); }
```

Update: After reading your comments it seems the column pckge_info.pckgeID likely doesn't exist. Double check to make sure you are calling the correct column name for the table you are querying.

Answer (score 0):

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

this occurs when your object is null so I would look into the query and see if **$result** object is populated, most likely **$result** is **null** when you are running the query and thus the error.